# My application URL is not open in PhantomJs browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs

I am running my scripts in PhantomJS browser. From last some of days these are not running on it. I tried to capture the screens but all I getting black screens. So I tried open a URL in phantomJS manually i.e. by command window and using below script to verify whether it is open or not.
This is my js file                         **loadspeed.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
 t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
phantom.exit();
}

t = Date.now();
address = system.args[1];
page.open(address, function(status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
console.log('FAIL to load the address');
} else {
t = Date.now() - t;
console.log('Loading ' + system.args[1]);
console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec ||  Loading time ' + (t/1000) + ' 
sec ' );
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

=========================================================================
1. By executing command in phantomjs window it gives loading time of any URL [image]

2. In my application case it fails [image]

**Note:** It is working fine on other browsers like chrome, firefox etc.

Is there any legitimate reason for this ? My all scripts are failing on PhantomJS. Any lead will highly appreciated.

3. PFA the screen that capture from firefox network console which shows **http** **GET** request is allowed on to url.
   [image]

Comment: so the first address works, the second not? can you prove that the second really works (that a GET request is allowed)?

Comment: What version is PhantomJS?

Comment: @Vaviloff i think v2.1.1 from the path

Comment: try `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true loadspeed.js`

Comment: @Vaviloff  Edvin is right the version I am using is 2.1.1 although I tried other versions also but problem is same in all versions.

Comment: @Vaviloff Thanks for this command. It works. It means this is related to SSL certification.

Comment: Elevated comment to an answer, included explanation of why it worked. (If it was useful you could upvote and accept the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the IP (10.40.1.20) from the second screenshot your site is hosted LAN and through https protocol. So I suppose you use a self-signed SSL-certificate that is, strictly speaking, not valid.

Therefore PhantomJS won't open this site unlesss you *specifically* tell it to ignore an invalid certificate with the use of `--ignore-ssl-errors` CLI switch:

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true loadspeed.js
```